# Как реализовать псевдоэлемент `:hover` из HTML в PyQt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qss, qpushbutton

Я хочу реализовать смену стиля кнопки при наведении на неё мышью.
Как это сделать?

Вот этот кусок кода, который не работает:

```
self.buttonPlay.setStyleSheet('''
    QPushButton:hover: {
        border: 1px;
        text-decoration: none;
    QPushButton#buttonPlay:hover {
    background-color: black;
''')
```

Answer (score 1):

Конечно не работает. И не заработает без валидного CSS. С таким CSS и в браузере тоже не заработает.

Чтоб заработало, надо убрать двоеточие после `hover`, и кол-во открывающих фигурных скобок должно быть равно кол-ву закрывающих.

В итоге получается так:

```
self.buttonPlay.setStyleSheet('''QPushButton:hover {
        border: 1px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    QPushButton#buttonPlay:hover {
        background-color: black;
    }
    ''')
```

Вот тут можно глянуть [примерчик](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19161119/5441023).

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import sys

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        main_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.buttonPlay = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button', self)
        self.buttonPlay.setGeometry(50, 50, 100, 100)



QSS = """
QPushButton {
    background: #0ff;
}
QPushButton:hover {
    background: #33f;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
"""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(QSS)
    w   = MainWindow()
    w.resize(200, 200)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]